# Generic object with common baseclass to std::function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a signal handling class with a Qt inspired interface like this:

```
class MessageConsumer {};

class MessageHandler {
public:
  static int Connect(int, MessageConsumer* obj, std::function<void(MessageConsumer&)> handler) { 
    // Add callback to handler 
    }      
};

class A : public MessageConsumer {
public:
  void handleIt(void) {
    // Do stuff
  }
};

int main(void) {
  A a;
  MessageHandler::Connect(1, &a, &A::handleIt);
  return 0;
}
```

But keep getting the compiler error:

```
main.cpp: In function ”int main()”:
main.cpp:71:46: error: no matching function ”MessageHandler::Connect(int, A*, void (A::*)())”
   MessageHandler::Connect(1, &a, &A::handleIt);
                                              ^
main.cpp:53:5: anm: candidate: static int MessageHandler::Connect(int, MessageConsumer*, std::function<void(MessageConsumer&)>)
 int MessageHandler::Connect(int, MessageConsumer* obj, std::function<void(MessageConsumer&)> handler) {
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:53:5: anm:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ”void (A::*)()” to ”std::function<void(MessageConsumer&)>”
```

Is there a way to solve this error without defining templates?  I do not want use templating in the interface, i.e.

```
MessageHandler::Connect<A>(1, &a, &A::handleIt)
```

Comment: *"i do not want use templating in the interface"* - why not?

Comment: How about using [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)?

Comment: The only reason is that I want it to look as much as Qt as possible

Comment: This is pretty explicit though: "no known conversion for argument 3 from ”void (A::*)()” to ”std::function”

Comment: The problem with emulating Qt is that Qt are using a special preprocessor to handle most of the signal/slot system. Unless you're willing to implement such a preprocessor emulating its system is going to be hard to impossible.

Comment: std::bind would be one of the steps in the Connect method, In the interface I want a function pointer

Comment: Functors surpass plain function pointers. Especially since C++ got lambdas.

Comment: @Johan: Tough because you're passing in a pointer-to-member-function

Comment: And even when using templates, you can still let the compiler auto-deduct the type when invoking the `Connect` function. If you don't want the `Connect<A>(...)` then it's usually possible to do plain `Connect(...)`

Comment: It is unclear what your intent is, with this over-engineered calling sequence. If your intent is for your `Connect()` to simply invoke a callback, at some point, then it just needs a single argument, a `std::function<void ()>`, without any extraneous pointers, that `Connect()` invokes directly. Then pass it a lambda that captures any needed object, by value or by reference, as appropriate, and call it a day.

Comment: @some programmer dude , it is? So then I just write my templatin as usual and then by magic it will work? Will test now :)

Comment: @some programmer guy, yeah, had the suspicion this was part of qt magic. Will go with the template version . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments the easiest way is to use a lambda function:

```
MessageHandler::Connect(1,&a, [](MessageConsumer& a) 
    { static_cast<A&>(a).handleIt(); });
```

See the fully compiling sample [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8ebfad56aee1600).

---

```
#include <functional>

class MessageConsumer {
};

class MessageHandler {
public:
  static int Connect(int, MessageConsumer* obj,  
                     std::function<void(MessageConsumer&)> handler) { 
        // Add callback to handler 
        return 0;
    }      
};

class A : public MessageConsumer {
public:
  void handleIt() {
    // Do stuff
  }
};

int main(void) {
  A a;
  MessageHandler::Connect(1,&a, [](MessageConsumer& a) 
      { static_cast<A&>(a).handleIt(); });
  return 0;
}
```